# Generate proxy classes from wsdl in IDL

Tags: wsdl, idl

I would like to generate proxy classes/code from a WSDL for [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29). So that I may communicate with [a SOAP service](http://api.echo.nasa.gov/echo/ws/v10/index.html).

Anyone know any tutorials or have any clue on how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use WseWsdl3 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx .

If WseWsdl3.exe is unable to create the proxy class, there is still a way.

If you can run your service as a regular ASP.NET web application in IIS, it creates temporary ASP.NET files where the proxy class is nicely generated for you.

You can find it in folder:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vMAJOR.MINOR.BUILD\Temporary ASP.NET Files\YOUR_WEB_APP.
There are some subfolders with random names, go to most recent one and look something like "App_WebReferences.XXXX.0.cs".

Comment: IDL... not ASP.NET. Wrong language. Thanks anyway.